# How to use a PLL to make a 50% duty cycle clock from a non 50% duty cycle clock

Tags: verilog, fpga

I am new to Verilog and I have been tasked to produce a new clock signal using a PLL (with which I am also not very familiar). The input clock is a 21 MHz 57% duty cycle clock (The clock cycle is meant to synchronize with 7 data bits so 4 bits are sent on the high part of the clock and the other 3 on the low). It is a Camera Link clock.

I want to produce a clock with 7 times the frequency so I can be synchronized with the 7 data bits that are incoming. Since I just want to trigger my logic on the positive edge, I guess the duty cycle of this output clock doesn't matter. But I am completely lost on how to do this.

I thought Maybe I could just create a clock divider because that is something I already know how to do. Since I know the frequency of the incoming clock is 21MHz, I could make a 21*7 MHz clock divider and just sync it with the original clock. But I want to know how to do this using a PLL.

Where do I start?

I am working with a Xilinx ML605

Comment: You haven't said what kind of hardware you're working with. PLLs are device-specific. Also, this question might be a better fit on [electronics.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Clocking Wizard](https://www.xilinx.com/products/intellectual-property/clocking_wizard.html) in Xilinx ISE. It will generate HDL code to instantiate a PLL on your hardware. It'll prompt you for the input and output frequency; from what you've described in your question, it sounds as though you have all the information it'll need to proceed.

The PLL is a hard macro on the FPGA, so it's not possible to describe in Verilog alone. It's possible to *instantiate* one directly (rather than using the Clocking Wizard), but figuring out the correct parameters to do so would be difficult, especially if you lack experience with the part.